# How to get a particular layer output of a pretrained VGG16 in pytorch

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, vgg-net

I am very new to pytorch and I am trying to get the output of the pretrained model VGG16 feature vector in 1*4096 format which is returned by the layers just before the final layer. I found that there are similar features available in keras. Is there any direct command in pytorch for the same?

The code I am using:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import models
from torch.autograd import Variable
from PIL import Image

image1 = Image.open(r"C:\Users\user\Pictures\user.png")

model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)

scaler = transforms.Resize((224, 224))
to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()

img = to_tensor(scaler(image1)).unsqueeze(0)

model(img).shape
model(img)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the network responsible for creating `features` is named... `features` (not only in VGG, it's like that for most of the pretrained networks inside `torchvision`).

Just use this field and pass your image like this:

```
import torch

import torchvision

image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\user\Pictures\user.png")

# Get features part of the network
model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True).features
tensor = transforms.ToTensor()(transforms.Resize((224, 224))(image)).unsqueeze(dim=0)

model(tensor)
```

#### EDIT:

To see what happens inside any `torchvision` model you can check it's source code. For VGG (any), there is a base class at the top of [this file](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/vgg.html).

To get `4096` flattened features, you could operations similar to those defined in `forward`:

```
# Tensor from previous code snippet for brevity

x = model.avgpool(tensor)
x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
final_x = model.classifier[0](x) # only first classifier layer
```

You could also iterate over `modules` or `children` up to wherever you want and output the result (or results or however you want)

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough. I am trying to get the output of the model just before the final output that is in the dimension 1* 1000. I want the output just before the final layer which is in 1 * 4096 format. The method above would give me the output from the features module which is in torch.Size([1, 512, 7, 7]).

Comment: Is that what you meant? Now you would get `(batch_size, 4096)` from pretrained `VGG`.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for :)